# Should I use "would be" or "would have been" in the following case?

Tags: conditional-constructions, backshifting, reported-speech

> He apologized for the poor product range. I told him it was okay: that I cared more about quality than quantity. And that if they worked as expected, even one **would be/have been** enough to meet the needs of my company.

Do I have to use *would be* or *would have been*? Why?

Comment: ...cared more *about* quality...

Answer (score 3):

"Would be".

Even though the extract as a whole is in the past tense, you are specifically referring to *what "you" told him*, and when you spoke to him, you would have been speaking in the present tense.

On the other hand, if you had been speaking to him *after* he had given you the products, you would say that just one *would have been* enough - because when you spoke to him, you would be speaking in the past tense.